# What's this 8 byte "padding" in the EGM2008 data?

Tags: geoid, egm96, egm2008

I recently downloaded the 1' earth gravitational model 2008 `Und_min1x1_egm2008_isw=82_WGS84_TideFree` dataset from [here](https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/egm08_wgs84.html). According to the [readme](https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/README_WGS84_2.pdf), the file consists of 233,301,600 32-bit floating point values in big-endian format, conceptually organized into 21600 "columns" and 10801 "rows". I wrote a program (in Go, but that's irrelevant) to sample this dataset and produce a greyscale image.

While examining the data, I noticed that the first 4 and last 4 bytes (or first and last values) for each row is identical through the whole dataset... `1.21072e-40` or the actual bytes `[0, 1, 81, 128]` (decimal).

The readme doesn't mention anything about this, as indicated above. In fact, it specifically says the 0-degree East value for each latitudinal "record" is **not** repeated at the end (360E) of the record. (I noticed this *was* the case in the 1996 dataset.) It's especially odd that it's all exactly the same data without any variation by latitude.

A search on google for those particular values (in hex) turned up a reference to CRC-24, but that seems like a long-shot.

I can easily compensate for this in my program, but does anyone have any idea what this "padding" is?

Sample generated image for fun:

[image: greyscale visualization of egm2008 data]